# easier way to validate $_GET id's

Tags: php

In my url i'm passing id's like this

```
localhost/?id=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I was wondering if there is a better way / simpler way to validate each id without using a loop?

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']))
    {
         $str = explode(',', $_GET['id']);

         for($ids = 0; $ids < sizeof($str); $ids++)
         {
             if (!ctype_digit($str[$ids]))
             {
                 echo 'error';
                 break;
             }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review and belongs on [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just test the string with a simple regular expression, eg

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d+,)*\d+$/', $_GET['id']) == 0) {
    throw new Exeption('error');
}
```

Comment: Probably the best method. @user2035819 should add a trailing comma to his urls to have it be compatible thought.